# Spring data query issue in ManytoOne maping

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

I am using Spring Data, along with postgresql. And I have ManyToOne mapping in City named entity calss. When i execute a select query i got following error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"City\"")
public class City implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="city_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer cityId;

    @Column(name="city_name")
    private String cityName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="state_id")
    private State state;

    @Column(name="district_name")
    private String districtName;

}



@Entity
@Table(name="\"State\"")
@NamedQuery(name="State.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM State s")
public class State implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="state_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer stateId;

    @Column(name="state_name")
    private String stateName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
    private Country country;

}


@Entity
@Table(name="\"Country\"")
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="country_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer countryId;

    @Column(name="country_name")
    private String countryName;

    @Column(name="sort_name")
    private String sortName;

    @Column(name="phone_code")
    private Integer phoneCode;

}

Repository
public interface CityRepository extends CrudRepository<City, Integer>{

    /**
     * @param countryId
     * @param cityName
     * @return
     */
    @Query("From City city where city.state.country.countryId =:countryId and city.cityName like:cityName and city.active = true")
    List<City> searchCityBynameAndCountryId(@Param("countryId") int countryId,@Param("cityName") String cityName);

}
```

> Actually I used to do Above mentioned query to featch data with where
>   clause in hibernate and Mysql combinations, But here i am using Spring
>   Data and Postgresql, while i am exicuting this select query i got
>   following error. Some one please help me to sort out this isue.

Error

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column
>   city0_.stateid does not exist   Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference
>   the column "city0_.state_id".   Position: 204

Comment: have you checked if the name of the stateId getter is getStateId and not getStateid?

Comment: No, actually i got this error while calling repository method.

Comment: Check on the entity class if the getter method for stateId is called getStateId and not getStateid

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Data then use IT. You don't need to write your own @Query for that simple query.

You need this:

```
List<City> findAllByStateCountryCountryIdAndCityNameLike(Integer countryId, String cityName);
```

I ommited last param from your Query `city.active = true"` because there is no field like that in your class.

Comment: sorry , it is there in entity class, i just removed it for shortening the code.

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column city0_.stateid does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "city0_.state_id".
  Position: 204

Comment: I tested it and worked for me. 
Did you create tables by your own, or hibernate created it for you?

Comment: i have created it my self

Comment: CREATE TABLE public."City"
(
  city_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"City_seq"'::regclass),
  city_name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  state_id integer NOT NULL,
  active boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  district_name character varying,
  pincode integer,
  CONSTRAINT "City_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (city_id),
  CONSTRAINT "stateId" FOREIGN KEY (state_id)
      REFERENCES public."State" (state_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
)

Comment: So the problem must be there. But it's weird. You have     @JoinColumn(name="state_id") so it should work. Anyway if you don't have any data inside or you don't need them, use create-drop and let hibernate create it for you. There must be some bug...I hope you didn't add Query to my method? :)

Comment: as u said i just drop the tables and created new tables and entity calsses now its working fine...